# multiple authors per post in mezzanine

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

How can I implement the possibility of having more than one author per blog post in mezzanine?

In my particular case, I will have blog posts that will be authored by more than one person.

==========================

@lightstrike

Thanks for your answer and email. I have this issue on STDBY as I have other more pressing matters I have to deal with in my app.

I have tried field injection to customize other issues and they worked OK.

On the issue in my question; I did try the field injection with the M2M field but It did not work. I did not get an error, but it did not work, at least as expected so I decided to work on the other issues and then come back to this one. By the way; I only gave field injection one shot so it might even be the case that I have a typo somewhere, absolutely no debugging or second thoughts were given as I had to move on.

The following might look OOT but hang on!

The good news is that, amongst other things, my app also needs some rather basic workflow control. I found [THIS SOLUTION](https://github.com/renyi/mezzanine-editor) which worked right out of the box. YES IT DID!

I learned about this app from an article in the [Mezzanine Users Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#%21forum/mezzanine-users) which link I know I have somewhere but will never find when I need it. Please look for it and read along as it is very eye opening. You will also learn that the name Reny gave it is indeed wrong, but I understand him as I'm also non English speaker and sometimes, when you translate it is hard to come up with the right names. Reny seems to be Italian (just a wild guess!) and I'm Spanish speaker. I know better (now) but "Editor" might well be a name I would have used.

Again, I have not had time to get back to the issue on this question but:

- IT WORKS and that is what matters. I think it can be done much better
  or should I say easier to use by the developer(s) by creating
  permissions in code and have the end user use those permissions (if
  needed). As of this moment you have to create a group to make the
  workflow "magic" happen (read his README.md for more info).
- Again this is just an idea. I have not even looked into the code in
  detail. I added the app, and then some half a dozen lines in
  settings.py and voila, it worked!
- HERE IS THE DEAL THOUGH: I think that whatever he is doing (and I
  have only looked superficially into his code) can also be done to
  implement collaborative authoring (have a look into his save_model
  method of the EditorBlogPostAdmin Class in admin.py)
- The solution will not be as simple as what I can infer from his code
  but something tells me this is the right path.

Just my two cents, but I will get back to this issue hopefully within the next 2 weeks and (hopefully) remember to post back here

I will nevertheless take a deeper look into this discussion again before trying anything else.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this out of the box with Mezzanine. If you look at the BlogPost model class with the [Mezzanine Blog app](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/models.py#L11), you will see the following:

```
class BlogPost(Displayable, Ownable, RichText, AdminThumbMixin):
```

The subclassing of Ownable turns out to be the important factor here. From line 6 of the models.py file of the Blog app, we know that the Ownable class was imported from Mezzanine's Core app:

```
class Ownable(models.Model):
"""
Abstract model that provides ownership of an object for a user.
"""

user = models.ForeignKey(user_model_name, verbose_name=_("Author"),
    related_name="%(class)ss")

class Meta:
    abstract = True

def is_editable(self, request):
    """
    Restrict in-line editing to the objects's owner and superusers.
    """
    return request.user.is_superuser or request.user.id == self.user_id
```

Due to the fact that Ownable defines a ForeignKey relationship, there can be many Ownable objects related to a single User object, but multiple User objects cannot be related to a single Ownable object. Since a BlogPost's author is defined this way, there can only be one author per blog post.

In order to allow multiple authors per blog post, you need to create a many-to-many (M2M) field so multiple User objects can be related to a single BlogPost object. To accomplish this, your best bet that doesn't involve changing Mezzanine's source code is to create a custom blog model by subclassing BlogPost:

### yourapp/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.utils.models import get_user_model_name
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost

user_model_name = get_user_model_name()

class CollaborativeBlogPost(BlogPost):
    """
    Custom model that subclasses Mezzanine's BlogPost to allow multiple authors
    """
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(user_model_name)

    def is_editable(self, request):
        """
        Customize is_editable method originally defined in Mezzanine's
        Ownable class to allow editing by all users
        """
        return request.user.is_superuser or 
            request.user.id in self.authors.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
```

You'll also want to add your new collaborative blog post to your admin. Using some pointers from [Mezzanine's field injection documentation](http://mezzanine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model-customization.html) (which I originally wanted to suggest but there are some issues with it when creating South migrations with ManyToManyFields), you can copy the base BlogPost admin and add the authors field:

### yourapp/admin.py

```
from copy import deepcopy
from django.contrib import admin                                   
from mezzanine.blog.admin import BlogPostAdmin                     
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost                         
from .models import CollaborativeBlogPost

blog_fieldsets = deepcopy(BlogPostAdmin.fieldsets)
blog_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(-2, "authors")

class MyBlogPostAdmin(BlogPostAdmin):
    fieldsets = blog_fieldsets

admin.site.register(CollaborativeBlogPost, MyBlogPostAdmin)
```

Depending on your needs you may need to add more admin logic, but hopefully this will get you started.